# Centering divs in rotated divs

Tags: css, rotation, centering

I am going crazy, I'm trying to center some divs (relatively to the viewport). 
The problem is that those divs that I want to center are nested in some rotated div (4deg).

```
.inner-wrap{
   width: 200vw;
   position: relative;
   padding: 20vh 0;
   right: -50vw;
   left: -50vw;
   bottom: -50px;
   transform-origin: bottom left;
   transform: rotate(-4deg);// HERE THE ROTATION
   margin: auto;
}
```

I corrected the angle for the text in the article nested in the `.inner-wrap`s

```
article{
  transform: rotate(4deg);
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

THE PROBLEM:
The two rotations let the content slide a bit on the left resulting a bit annoying see the link :)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw4B9Lk7vRtda3p4TWpWNzhBZVU/view?usp=sharing

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the HTML or a sample page we can look at?

Comment: I just uploaded the problem here :)   [link](http://tryout.campitura.it) try to look at it in developer mode as device

Comment: Hmm, everything seems to look fine for me. What browser / OS are you in?

Comment: try in mobile, the problem shows up in mobile

Comment: I see it now, check my answer out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm an idiot! I setted the rotation origin as bottom left instead of center ....

Answer (score 2):

You can try giving a width to the titles, then position it relative to your window with `50%` and `margin-left: -(half of the width of the element)` In this case I used `-140px`

```
section.who article.logo {
    max-width: 280px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -140px;
}
```

Comment: It half works I mean, it works on pure 'section.who article.logo ' but if i nest something else it crash

Comment: No, it doesn't work because I had to set the '.inner-wrap' width at 200vw in order to cut off some orrible angles :(

Comment: I was just about to say this might be one of those things you'll have to eye up, but it seems like you figured it out. Congrats!